# How do I know my heroku app is actually grabbing assets from cloudfront AWS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku

I setup CloudFront AWS to host my static assets for my Heroku App by following this article:

[How to speed up your Rails app with Cloudfront](http://www.happybearsoftware.com/use-cloudfront-and-the-rails-asset-pipeline-to-speed-up-your-app.html)

I setup the CDN url on AWS and added to my config/environments/staging.rb file:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "xxxx.cloudfront.net"
```

I deployed to my staging environment and find that my page loads are slower.  I do inspect element on chrome and it all seems fine (the assets are coming from cloudfront).  However, when I look at my Heroku Logs, I see the following:

```
        2015-08-08T00:40:52.667517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
path="/assets/ajaxSpinner.gif"
        host=xxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=326eaf7b-erf5-wr5a-954b-86fwefwwf fwd="xx.xxx.xxx.193" 
    dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=31ms status=200 bytes=19488
```

Should the "path" be something like: "**xxxx.cloudfront.net**/assets/ajaxSpinner.gif"??? OR, should the "host" be "**xxxx.cloudfront.net**"???

Comment: is your `ajaxSpinner.gif` served from `AWS`? I think while rendering `HTML` rails just keeps the `src` to the `image` and the browser requests the `asset` from `AWS` not from your `Heroku` app. How your `Rails Log` showing the file request log.

Comment: No, I am not using AWS to host the static assets (including those images).

Comment: Heroku Logs should show my rails logs right? How do i look at Rails logs?

Comment: is this question now valid, if needed please edit the question @Rav Johal

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood your previous question.  I am precompiling my assets to cloudfront.  I suppose that AWS is "hosting" those assets.  But they are actually within my application, just cached on cloudfront.  So the question is still valid.